# Pandas Grouping By Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, hour

I'm attempting to count the number of users that login to a system on an hourly basis on a given date. The date I have resembles:

```
df=

Name      Date
name_1    2012-07-12 22:20:00
name_1    2012-07-16 22:19:00
name_1    2013-12-16 17:50:00
...
name_2    2010-01-11 19:54:00 
name_2    2010-02-06 12:10:00
...
name_2    2012-07-18 22:12:00
...
name_5423 2013-11-23 10:21:00
```

since I'm not interested in the users name I've deleted that column. I manage to create a grouped data structure and a new dataframe `df2` using the following command

```
grp = df.groupby(by=[df.Date.map(lambda x: (x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour))])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Count' : grp.size()}).reset_index()
```

`grp` converts the `datetime` type into a tuple of `(year, month, day, hour)`.

I'm able to convert it back to a `datetime` type using a `for` loop

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
    proper_date = datetime.datetime(*df2['Date'][i])
    df2.set_value(i, 'Date', proper_date)
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a better/more efficient way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `Date` converted to `h` and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (df.Date.values.astype('datetime64[h]'))
['2012-07-12T22+0200' '2012-07-16T22+0200' '2013-12-16T17+0100'
 '2010-01-11T19+0100' '2010-02-06T12+0100' '2012-07-18T22+0200'
 '2013-11-23T10+0100']

print (df.Name.groupby([df.Date.values.astype('datetime64[h]')]).size())
2010-01-11 19:00:00    1
2010-02-06 12:00:00    1
2012-07-12 22:00:00    1
2012-07-16 22:00:00    1
2012-07-18 22:00:00    1
2013-11-23 10:00:00    1
2013-12-16 17:00:00    1
dtype: int64
```

Another solution:

```
print (df.Date.values.astype('<M8[h]'))
['2012-07-12T22+0200' '2012-07-16T22+0200' '2013-12-16T17+0100'
 '2010-01-11T19+0100' '2010-02-06T12+0100' '2012-07-18T22+0200'
 '2013-11-23T10+0100']

print (df.Name.groupby([df.Date.values.astype('<M8[h]')]).size())
2010-01-11 19:00:00    1
2010-02-06 12:00:00    1
2012-07-12 22:00:00    1
2012-07-16 22:00:00    1
2012-07-18 22:00:00    1
2013-11-23 10:00:00    1
2013-12-16 17:00:00    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Or possibly: `df.Date.round('H')` for the group key

Comment: Why not simply: `grouper = df['Date'].dt.hour`; `df.groupby(grouper).count()`?

Comment: @Kartik Because you need truncate from datetime only minutes and seconds, set them to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using resampling. Not very efficient, I think, but interesting.

```
# Test data
d = {'Date': ['2012-07-12 22:20:00', '2012-07-12 22:19:00', '2013-12-16 17:50:00', '2010-01-11 19:54:00', '2010-02-06 12:10:00', '2012-07-18 22:12:00'],
     'Name': ['name_1', 'name_1', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_2', 'name_5']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
result = df.set_index('Date')

# Resampling data for each hour
result = result.resample('H').count()
# Filtering to keep only hours with at least one row
result[result['Name'] > 0]

                     Name
Date                     
2010-01-11 19:00:00     1
2010-02-06 12:00:00     1
2012-07-12 22:00:00     2
2012-07-18 22:00:00     1
2013-12-16 17:00:00     1
```